# Unable to get value of element using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom, newrelic, custom-attributes

For the below element i am trying to capture my name displayed in this tag. Part of the code snippet attached.

```
  <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
 <div class="user-panel">
    <!--<div class="pull-left image">
      <img id="profileImage2" alt="User Image" class="img-circle" />
    </div>-->
    <a>
    <div class="pull-left info">
      <p class="nameprofile1">Hi<input id="inputName" disabled="disabled" style="width:auto !Important;"></p>
      <!--<a href="#Profilezone" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i>
        Online</a>-->
    </div>
    </a>
    </div>
```

I am unable to capture the value of text by using

```
var Name=document.getElementById("inputName").value;
newrelic.setCustomAttribute('Name', Name);
```

This is to set a custom attribute for Newrelic event. I am querying the attribute Name using the query

```
SELECT Name FROM PageView WHERE appName ='Sharepoint_Custom'
```

Result is Null.

Is there something i need to understand as this element is nested but visible on the main landing page.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Post your real time ```HTML``` element instead of image.. If possible create some example reproducing your issue..

Comment: How do you know that there's no value in `Name`? I mean you're never using the variable nor haven't introduced any error message.

Comment: Why don't you just open the DevTools, and check the error messages. If not any, then after assigned the name, log it to the console to see the value of the variable, or even better, set a breakpoint after assigned the variable, and check the value when the execution breaks. Debugging JS on the server is probably one of the things you should not do ... Also, without thinking too much, make sure the element __and the value__ exists at the time you're assigning the variable, it's no use to try to refer a non-existing element, or post the empty string.

Comment: Your input is disabled and has no value set so the value will always be blank?